# Template typedef of function pointer in c++

Tags: c++, function, templates, pointers, typedef

Imagine I have a template class, where I've defined typdedef of function pointer to BaseClass function, that returns T and has no arguments:

```
template <typename T, typename BaseClass> class TConnectionPoint
{
    typedef   T (BaseClass::* PConnectionFunction)();
    private:
       PConnectionFunction _func;
    public:
       T Call();
}
```

This template has method Call():

```
template <typename T, typename BaseClass> T TConnectionPoint<T,BaseClass>::Call()
{
    return _func();
}
```

The problem appears when I try to execute Call() function - VS2013 send me this error, which is a little confusing me:

> term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typedef defines `PConnectionFunction` to be a *member* function pointer, not a plain function pointer. You can call member functions only on an object, like this:

```
template <typename T, typename BaseClass> 
T TConnectionPoint<T,BaseClass>::Call(BaseClass& b)
{
    return (b.*_func)();
}
```

If instead you want to call *static* member functions ob `BaseClass`, then the function pointer needs to be a normal function pointer, not a member function pointer:

```
typedef   T (* PConnectionFunction)();
```

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to member function can only be dereferenced in combination with an object (on which the function will be invoked). You need access to an object of type `BaseClass` to use it.

For example, you could change `Call()` like this:

```
template <typename T, typename BaseClass>
T TConnectionPoint<T,BaseClass>::Call(BaseClass &obj)
{
    return (obj.*_func)();
}
```